# Why do Ruby -rdebug and IRB give different results for the same program?

Tags: ruby, debugging, irb, feedparser

Running exactly the same Ruby program that requires feedparser lib. It runs OK in IRB but failed in parsing the same input with a "invalid date" exception when I run it with `ruby -rdebug`. I double checked lib searching path in both methods, they are the same as following.

```
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/mipsel-linux
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/mipsel-linux
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/mipsel-linux
```

Comment: Can you reduce the code to a minimal failing example and post that here?

Comment: Without data samples and your code we can't help you.